# Webpack webpack-dev-server + axios + php - how do they work?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, axios, webpack-dev-server

I am using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development#using-webpack-dev-server) to run my Vue app.

webpack config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
})
```

a vue component:

```
let result = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/xxx/data.php'
})
console.log(result.data)
```

When I run:

```
$ npm run start
```

And my site is served at `http://localhost:8080`

But `console.log(result.data)` does not return data that should be processed by the php file, it returns the php code in text instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1/xxx/data.php
<?php
....
....
....
```

Any ideas why?

Notes:

1. I have php running on LAMP already and i **can** execute the php file at http://127.0.0.1/xxx/data.php and get the processed data.

Comment: I believe this means that your php-engine is not doing it's job. It's not compiling the php code into JSON or whatever you want to send back on the request.

Comment: Have you tried curling the endpoint or something? Should see the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack doesn't process php files, for it the php file are only a text file, you need mount a local server like Wamp, xamp or use the build in php server to process it.

Comment: I have php running on LAMP already and i can execute the php file at http://127.0.0.1/xxx/data.php

Comment: The lamp server isn't  doing it's job, maybe is a miss configuration in the .htaccess. Try with the build in php server: http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

webpack uses js, not php

you still need to use nodejs to compile your files, but if you want to serve php content, you will need to use php **INSTEAD** of nodejs

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is nothing wrong with the code but it is webpack-dev-server that causing the problem - it does not 'refresh' browser for the updated code even though this is what it does! So I have to clean my browser caches and refresh my browser manually then i get the result. obviously it is not a reliable plugin!